# Debian stable: Only GNOME classic with custom 3.16

Tags: debian, kernel, gnome

I compiled a custom 3.16.2 today, which works flawlessly except that GNOME only starts in classic mode.

Maybe this is due to changes in the drm i915 driver, but how would I debug this?

System is a Lenovo T400, Debian stable 32bit, Intel GM45 graphics chipset.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in kernel 3.15 and 3.16 that prevent proper initialization of the graphics hardware. To know whether you're affected, run `dmesg | grep "render ring initialization failed"`

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76554

[A patch is available](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=104224) that applies cleanly to 3.16.3, [it is already in the stable tree](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ece4a17d237a79f63fbfaf3f724a12b6d500555c) and in the 3.17-rc series.